# How can we update the canonical tags for sub URLs using angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, seo, canonical-link

I put the following link in the `index.html` => It's successfully used by SEO tools:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com">
```

For sub-URLs I have the following code and function called in the constructor. But, it's not picked up by SEO tools:

```
constructor() {
    this.setCanonicalURL();
}

canonicalUrl: string = '';
getCanonicalUrl(): string {
    let currentUrl = this.route.url;
    return 'https://example.com' + currentUrl;
}

setCanonicalURL(): void {
    this.canonicalUrl = this.getCanonicalUrl();
    this.manageCanonicalLink(this.canonicalUrl)
}

manageCanonicalLink(url: string) {
    const existingCanonicalLink = document.querySelector('link[rel="canonical"]');
    if (existingCanonicalLink) {
      existingCanonicalLink.setAttribute('href', url);
    } else {
      const canonicalLink = document.createElement('link');
      canonicalLink.rel = 'canonical';
      canonicalLink.href = url;
      document.head.appendChild(canonicalLink);
    }
}
```

When I inspect the element, it's updated successfully. But when I checked in the SEO tool it's not taking. like, it's updated the `https://example.com` not updating `https://example.com/page`

[image]

Can anyone please suggest what was I missing here?

Comment: What SEO tools are you using?  Not all of them can parse JavaScript.  Google should be able to use your JavaScript.  Have you tested with Google Search Console?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using seoability and seositecheckup. they both are not detecting. The Google search console takes time to update results. so, i need to confirm whether any of the tools like my website are taking or not. Can you suggest the best way to check?

Comment: Inspecting the DOM as you said you are already doing is the only step I would take before Google Search Console.

Comment: In Dom It's showing correctly. It seemed to me that it was not showing because of SEO tool was read first and my DOM updated after that. But I do not write any timeout or anything else that takes time to update DOM.